# What is the norm divided by the dimension of the vector called?

Tags: reference-request, vectors, normed-spaces

I have a vector $v = \{v_1, v_2, ...v_d\}$ with $d$ dimensions. Is there a name for

$$
\frac{\|v\|}{d}
$$

---

**Note**:

This question occurred because I need this to compare the values of two vectors with different dimensions: which has the largest sum of absolute values. Maybe there is a name for this that doesn't involve the norm?

Comment: If you’re interest in the largest sum of absolute values, why don’t you just use this, that is [the manhattan norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_norm#Absolute-value_norm)?

Comment: @k.stm Re gidi, I need to compare two vectors with different dimensions. The larger one might have smaller values but a larger norm due to its larger size. I want to compare them independent of their size so I divide with the number of dimensions $d$. Is there a fancy way of saying this?

Comment: This almost looks like the root mean square value of the vector. This would be so if the norm you use is the 2-norm (Euclidian norm), and the $d$ should be replaced by a $\sqrt{d}$. Maybe if you give some more context on where you needed to compare this for, a better context? In pure math/linear algebra for example, I would not know, but in thermodynamics for example, your equation is how the temperature is related to a velocity vector $v$.